# Display multiple print lines from another function into multiline using PySimpleGui

Tags: pysimplegui

I am trying to display all the print lines that occur in a function

```
def colorselected(val):
    if val > 50 :
       print("This has breached the threshold")
       print("Red")
       print("Exit program")
   else:
       print("All good")
       print("Green")
       print("Continue")
```

Layout is

```
layout = [
    [sg.Text("ColorValue"),
            sg.Input(size=(8, 1), enable_events=True, key="-COLORIS-"),
            sg.Button('Show')          ,
            sg.Multiline(size=(50,2), key="-coloroutput-")
            
    ]
```

And the loop for the PySimpleGui section

```
while True:
    event, values = window.read()    
    if event == "Show":
       display_output=colorselected(50)
       window['-coloroutput-'].print(display_output)
```

Output in the console shows the print statement but not inside the PySimpleGui Multiline text area. It shows None

Answer (score 1):

Some issues in your code

- There's value returned by your function `colorselected`
- Bracket missed in your `layout`

Options can be added in Multiline element

- `reroute_stdout=True` to print directly to Multiline
- `do_not_clear=False` to clear content of Multiline for each event
- try/except statement used when convert the content of the Input to float

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def colorselected(val):

    if val > 50 :
       print("This has breached the threshold")
       color = "Red"
       print("Red")
       print("Exit program")
    else:
       print("All good")
       color = 'Green'
       print("Green")
       print("Continue")
    return color

layout = [
    [sg.Text("ColorValue"),
     sg.Input(size=(8, 1), key="-COLORIS-"),
     sg.Button('Show')],
    [sg.Multiline(size=(50,2), key="-coloroutput-")]
]
window = sg.Window('Draw', layout, finalize=True)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == "Show":
        try:
            val = float(values["-COLORIS-"])
            display_output=colorselected(val)
            window['-coloroutput-'].print(display_output)
        except ValueError:
            window['-coloroutput-'].print("Wrong value")

window.close()
```

Comment: reroute_stdout=True to print directly to Multiline  <--- This did the trick! Thanks!